# How to check render slot (is empty or with rendered image)?

Tags: python, rendering

the only thing I found in other addons is trying to save rendered image

```
import bpy
from sys import platform

nullpath = '/nul' if platform == 'win32' else '/dev/null'

img = bpy.data.images['Render Result']
active = img.render_slots.active_index
slots = ''

for i in range(0,len(img.render_slots)):
    img.render_slots.active_index = i
    try:
        img.save_render(nullpath)
        slots = slots + '1'
    except RuntimeError:
        slots = slots + '0'
        
img.render_slots.active_index = active
print(slots)
```

any else solution?